# How to fix (quote keys in) ill-formed JSON?

Tags: json, bash

```
# http://www.google.com/ig/calculator?hl=zh-cn&q=1RMB=?USD
{lhs: "1人民币",rhs: "0.158469 美元",error: "",icc: true}
```

It's a `javascript` object, but not a `json` string:

```
{"lhs": "1人民币","rhs": "0.158469 美元","error": "","icc": true}
```

I don't think it's a good idea to use `sed`.
Is there a tool to fix this ill-formed json?

Comment: Bad google. Why are they doing this to us?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$ js -e 'print(JSON.stringify({lhs: "1人民币",rhs: "0.158469 美元",error: "",icc: true}))'
{"lhs":"1人民币","rhs":"0.158469 美元","error":"","icc":true}
```

*runs*